# How to call a REST end point using Airflow DAG

Tags: rest, docker, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm new to Apache Airflow. I want to call a REST end point using DAG.
REST end point for example

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api/employees", consumes = "application/json")
```

Now I want to call this rest end point using Airflow DAG, and schedule it. What I'm doing is using SimpleHttpOperator to call the Rest end point.

```
t1 = SimpleHttpOperator(
task_id='post_op',
endpoint='http://localhost:8084/api/employees',
data=json.dumps({"department": "Digital","id": 102,"name": "Rakesh","salary": 80000}),
headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
dag=dag,)
```

When I trigger the DAG the task is getting failed

```
[2019-12-30 09:09:06,330] {{taskinstance.py:862}} INFO - Executing <Task(SimpleHttpOperator): 
post_op> on 2019-12-30T08:57:00.674386+00:00
[2019-12-30 09:09:06,331] {{base_task_runner.py:133}} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 
'example_http_operator', 'post_op', '2019-12-30T08:57:00.674386+00:00', '--job_id', '6', '--pool', 
'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/ExampleHttpOperator.py', '--cfg_path', 
'/tmp/tmpf9t6kzxb']
[2019-12-30 09:09:07,446] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask post_op [2019-12-30 
09:09:07,445] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-12-30 09:09:07,446] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask post_op [2019-12-30 
09:09:07,446] {{dagbag.py:92}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from 
/usr/local/airflow/dags/ExampleHttpOperator.py
[2019-12-30 09:09:07,473] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask post_op [2019-12-30 
09:09:07,472] {{cli.py:545}} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: example_http_operator.post_op 2019-12- 
30T08:57:00.674386+00:00 [running]> on host 855dbc2ce3a3
[2019-12-30 09:09:07,480] {{http_operator.py:87}} INFO - Calling HTTP method
[2019-12-30 09:09:07,483] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-12-30 09:09:07,483] 
{{base_hook.py:84}} INFO - Using connection to: id: http_default. Host: https://www.google.com/, 
Port: None, Schema: None, Login: None, Password: None, extra: {}
[2019-12-30 09:09:07,484] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-12-30 09:09:07,484] 
{{http_hook.py:131}} INFO - Sending 'POST' to url: 
https://www.google.com/http://localhost:8084/api/employees
[2019-12-30 09:09:07,501] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-12-30 09:09:07,501] 
{{http_hook.py:181}} WARNING - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries 
exceeded with url: /http://localhost:8084/api/employees (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: 
SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')"))) Tenacity will retry to execute the operation
[2019-12-30 09:09:07,501] {{taskinstance.py:1058}} ERROR - 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: 
/http://localhost:8084/api/employees (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 
'Unexpected EOF')")))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 485, in wrap_socket
cnx.do_handshake()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1934, in do_handshake
self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1664, in _raise_ssl_error
raise SysCallError(-1, "Unexpected EOF")
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (-1, 'Unexpected EOF')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
chunked=chunked,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 394, in connect
ssl_context=context,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 491, in wrap_socket
raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)
```

Airflow is running on Docker and the docker image is **puckel/docker-airflow**. 
Why it is calling the host **http_default. Host: https://www.google.com/**

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider both the `Operator` you are using and the underlying `Hook` which it uses to connect.
The `Hook` fetches connection information from an `Airflow Connection` which is just a container used to store credentials and other connection information. You can configure `Connections` in the Airflow UI (using the Airflow UI -> Admin -> Connections).

So in this case, you need to first configure your HTTP `Connection`.

From the [http_hook documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/_api/airflow/providers/http/hooks/http/index.html#module-airflow.providers.http.hooks.http):

```
http_conn_id (str) – connection that has the base API url i.e https://www.google.com/
```

It so happens that for the `httpHook`, you should configure the `Connection` by setting the `host` argument equal to the `base_url` of your endpoint: `http://localhost:8084/`.

Since your operator has the default `http_conn_id`, the hook will use the `Airflow Connection` called "http_default" in the Airflow UI.
If you don't want to change the default one you can create another `Airflow Connection` using the Airflow UI, and pass the new conn_id argument to your operator.

See the [source code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/_api/airflow/providers/http/operators/http/index.html#module-airflow.providers.http.operators.http) to get a better idea how the `Connection` object is used.

Lastly, according to the [http_operator documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/_api/airflow/providers/http/operators/http/index.html#module-airflow.providers.http.operators.http):

```
endpoint (str) – The relative part of the full url. (templated)
```

You should only be passing the *relative* part of your URL to the operator. The rest it will get from the underlying `http_hook`.

In this case, the value of `endpoint` for your `Operator` should be `api/employees` (not the full URL).

The Airflow project documentation is unfortunately not very clear in this case. Please consider contributing an improvement, they are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set your ENV variable of connection string in your Dockerfile or docker run command:

```
ENV AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN my_conn_string
```

see [this](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/set-config.html#setting-configuration-options) and [this](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow#configurating-airflow)

> Connections
>
> The connection information to external systems is stored in the
>   Airflow metadata database and managed in the UI (Menu -> Admin ->
>   Connections) A conn_id is defined there and hostname / login /
>   password / schema information attached to it. Airflow pipelines can
>   simply refer to the centrally managed conn_id without having to hard
>   code any of this information anywhere.
>
> Many connections with the same conn_id can be defined and when that is
>   the case, and when thehooks uses the get_connection method from
>   BaseHook, Airflow will choose one connection randomly, allowing for
>   some basic load balancing and fault tolerance when used in conjunction
>   with retries.
>
> Airflow also has the ability to reference connections via environment
>   variables from the operating system. The environment variable needs to
>   be prefixed with AIRFLOW_CONN_ to be considered a connection. When
>   referencing the connection in the Airflow pipeline, the conn_id should
>   be the name of the variable without the prefix. For example, if the
>   conn_id is named POSTGRES_MASTER the environment variable should be
>   named AIRFLOW_CONN_POSTGRES_MASTER. Airflow assumes the value returned
>   from the environment variable to be in a URI format
>   (e.g.postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/master).

see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/nqCeqpDRiTg)

therefore you are now using the default:

```
Using connection to: id: http_default. Host: https://www.google.com/
```